# Accessing current IPrinciple in a Master View in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I currently have a abstract controller class that I all my controllers inherit from. 
I want to be able to use the current user (IPrinciple) object in my master page.
I read that I could use the contructor of my abstract base controller class, that is I could do something like

```
public BaseController()
    {
        ViewData["UserName"] = this.User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

I could then access ViewData["UserName"] etc from my master page.
My problem is that this.User is null at this point.
Does anybody know of a different approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write an [ActionFilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) and in the `OnActionExecuted` event put the user inside `ViewData`:

```
public class UserActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["UserName"] = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

And then decorate your base controller with this attribute:

```
[UserActionFilter]
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{ }
```